# How would you go through each row and each column seperatly in two dimensional array

Tags: java

I am just curious as to how that is done. I am writing a small program to get a better understanding of two dimensional arrays. I want to know how I can go though each row and then each column separately using for loops.

Lets say I have a 2D array that is made out of different letters. I want to go through each row and each column and check if a certain letter is there. Then I want it to print how many occurrences of this letter happened in each row and then each column.

First index is row and second index is column.

Comment: What do you mean, separately?

Comment: `using a for loop`, Only 1? You need a nested for loop if you want to keep track of both indexes.

Comment: So it goes only through first column, then second column, not involving any rows.

Comment: John... do you want it to iterate over every row in the first column then move to the second, or do you want to handle the entire array of rows for the first column?

Comment: Please indicate the structure of your grid. 2D array is ambiguous. How is it declared? Which index is the row/col etc.

Comment: Basically every row and then check every column. Not handle entire array.

Comment: Have you tried something? You just changed your question from a broad one to a more specific one.

Comment: I tried using a for loop however i dont have a good understanding of for loops and i was wondering how not just go through array in its entirety but small bits like rows and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `something[][]` is an `something[]` of `something`-rows (that is `something[i]` gives us a row, not a column - if it'S the way round, just change the examples):

```
public static void loopExample (String[][] someTwoDimArray) {
    // Looping rows
    for (var row = 0 ; row < someTwoDimArray.length ; row++) {
        for (var col = 0 ; col < someTwoDimArray[0].length ; col++) {
           System.out.println(someTwoDimArray[row][col]);
        }
    }

    // looping columns
    for (var col = 0 ; col < someTwoDimArray[0].length ; col++) {
        for (var row = 0 ; row < someTwoDimArray.length ; row++) {
           System.out.println(someTwoDimArray[row][col]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the first or second index is considered rows or columns, but this is a pretty standard nested loop for iterating over every element of a 2d array.

```
for(int column = 0; column < array.length(); ++column) {
    for(int row = 0; row < array[column].length(); ++row) {
        // do stuff to array[column][row]
    }
}
```

Given your update, let's look for the letter `'N'`, in a 2d char array called `myLetters`.

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < myLetters.length(); ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < myLetters[i].length(); ++j) {
        if('N' == myLetters[i][j]) {
            ++counter;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("N occurs " + counter + " times.");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a 2D array if you want to access each cell you will have to use a nested for loop.

eg:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length1; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<length2; j++){
    // do something
    to format column first do array[i][j] = //do something
    to format row first do array[j][i] = // do something
    }


"I tried using a for loop however i dont have a good understanding of for loops and i was wondering how not just go through array in its entirety but small bits like rows and columns"
```

A for loop is a java control flow statement. It lets you initialize a variable (i and j) it gives you a condition (i

```
int i = 0
while (i < length1){
//do something
i++
}
```

if working with arrays for loops are almost always required.